# Dynamic image gallery from images in database in diffident folders

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a project where an admin is able to upload multiple pictures into a database into different folders. I have PHP code where the images are taken from the database, the problem I have is that I am trying to show the pictures on the web page dynamically without the limit which I currently have which is 10 images.
this is my code below for getting the images.

```
  $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ewsc_picture_gallery WHERE ewsc_picture_gallery_folder = '".$_GET['gallery']."'");
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
$numrows = $result->num_rows;
                
    if ($numrows==1){
        while($show = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){                
            $ewsc_picture_gallery_id = $show['ewsc_picture_gallery_id'];
            $ewsc_picture_gallery_title = $show['ewsc_picture_gallery_title'];                        
            $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder = $show['ewsc_picture_gallery_folder'];
        }
    }
    else {
    $error = "<div class=\"label label-danger\">FATAL ERROR!! This page will restart your machine. Please close this page.</div>";
}
$sql->close();
$conn->close();


the below code is for displaying the images in a gallery on the web page.

    <div id="HomeSlider">
                        <!-- #region Jssor Slider Begin -->
                        <!-- Generated by Jssor Slider Maker. -->
                        <!-- This demo works without jquery library. -->
                    
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../homeslider/jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
                        <!-- use jssor.slider.debug.js instead for debug -->
                        <script type="application/javascript" src="../../homeslider/jssorslider.js">    </script>
                    
                    
                        <div id="jssor_1" class="SliderContainer">

                    
                            <div data-u="slides" class="TheSlides"><!-- BEGINNING OF SLIDES -->

                                <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;"> 
                                    <a href="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/1.jpg" target="_blank"><img data-u="image" src="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/1.jpg" /></a>
                                </div> 

                                <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;"> 
                                    <a href="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/2.jpg" target="_blank"><img data-u="image" src="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/2.jpg" /></a>
                                </div> 

                                <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;"> 
                                    <a href="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/3.jpg" target="_blank"><img data-u="image" src="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/3.jpg" /></a>
                                </div> 

                                <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;"> 
                                    <a href="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/4.jpg" target="_blank"><img data-u="image" src="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/4.jpg" /></a>
                                </div> 

                                <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;"> 
                                    <a href="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/5.jpg" target="_blank"><img data-u="image" src="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/5.jpg" /></a>
                                </div> 

                                <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;"> 
                                    <a href="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/6.jpg" target="_blank"><img data-u="image" src="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/6.jpg" /></a>
                                </div> 

                                <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;"> 
                                    <a href="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/7.jpg" target="_blank"><img data-u="image" src="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/7.jpg" /></a>
                                </div> 

                                <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;"> 
                                    <a href="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/8.jpg" target="_blank"><img data-u="image" src="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/8.jpg" /></a>
                                </div> 

                                <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;"> 
                                    <a href="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/9.jpg" target="_blank"><img data-u="image" src="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/9.jpg" /></a>
                                </div> 

                                <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;"> 
                                    <a href="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/10.jpg" target="_blank"><img data-u="image" src="<?php echo $ewsc_picture_gallery_folder;?>/10.jpg" /></a>
                                </div>                          
                                
                            </div><!-- END OF SLIDES -->
                            
                            <!-- Bullet Navigator -->
                            <div data-u="navigator" class="jssorb05" style="bottom:60px;right:16px;" data-autocenter="1">
                                <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
                                <div data-u="prototype" style="width:16px;height:16px;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <script>
                            jssor_1_slider_init();
                        </script>
                    
                        <!-- #endregion Jssor Slider End -->
                    
                    </div>
```